# Recursion Oracle pl/sql using cursors

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchical-data

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE regions
(
        PARENT_NAME     VARCHAR2(30),
        CHILD_NAME      VARCHAR2(30)
);
```

I need to perform recursion using cursors in Pl/SQL  like that accepts a region name (CHILD_NAME) from the user input and display all its parent regions.
Any suggestions?.

Comment: Are you sure you need recursion for this?

Comment: @zander Dear pseudo code is going to be like this
v_child_name
v_partent_name
select parent_name into v_partent_name from region where child_name  = v_child_name;
On the very next iteration v_parent_name should become child till the output is not null.

Answer (score 7):

```
select parent_name
from regions
start with child_name = :CHILD_NAME
connect by prior parent_name = child_name;
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. Can you provide me the pl/sql statement for that....

Comment: Are you asking how to incorporate a SQL statement into PL/SQL? Read the docs, they're an excellent introduction to PL/SQL - e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS551